# Doubt regarding resolution of tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

So, I have this code:

> Credits to @Marmot

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{layout}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
        \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[local cs/.style={shift={(#1.south west)},x={(#1.south
        east)-(#1.south west)},y={(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)}}]
            \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tab) {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25}  \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}};
            \begin{scope}[local cs=tab,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
             \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=-1em]0,0)
             -- ([yshift=-1em]1,0) node[pos=5/12,below]{independent\\
             variables} node[pos=5/6,anchor=north west]{dependent\\
             variables};
             \draw[double=black,double distance=0.8pt,white,thick] (5/6,-0.2em) 
             -- ++(0,-1.6em);
             \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([xshift=1em]1,0) -- ([xshift=1em]1,1)
              node[pos=2/9,right]{test\\rows}
              node[pos=13/18,right]{training\\rows};
             \draw[double=black,double distance=0.8pt,white,thick]
             ([xshift=0.2em]1,4/9) -- ++ (1.6em,0);
            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}

        }
        \hfill
        \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[local cs/.style={shift={(#1.south west)},x={(#1.south
        east)-(#1.south west)},y={(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)}}]
            \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (tab) {\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25}  \\ \hline
                &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}   \\ \hline
                &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
                & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
                &  &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} &   \\ \hline
                &  &\cellcolor{gray!25}  &  &  &   \\ \hline
            \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &  & \\ \hline
                & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
                &  &  & \cellcolor{gray!25} &  &\cellcolor{gray!25} \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}};
            \begin{scope}[local cs=tab,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
             \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=-1em]0,0)
             -- ([yshift=-1em]1,0) node[pos=1/2,below]{no demarcation between
             independent\\ and dependent variables};
             \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([xshift=1em]1,0) -- ([xshift=1em]1,1)
              node[pos=1/2,right]{no\\ demarcation\\ between\\ training and\\ test rows};
            \end{scope}
           \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

They look like this:
[image]

If you don't have anything to compare it with, you would say that once the code is compiled in LateX, they look fantastic. However, I came across this cube, which has way more definition/resolution and it was created with tikZ as well. How is it possible that this is happening? Is there any option to set up the resolution?

Here is the cube:
[image]

> Update. Now I’m using @Marmot’s new code and I was able to took a screen shot to compare. They actually, meaning, light blue, are not the same, cube’s a little brighter(cell with number 5):

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'resolution'? Sharpness? Anti-aliasing? I doubt that there is an actual difference between the images, it the viewer and the screen also influence the appearance. Try printing both on paper and check if you can see any difference.

Comment: I would say Sharpness. Plus the lines are thinner, but that can be modified. And yes, from my perspective and IMHO, there is a huge difference in terms of Sharpness

Comment: @Delan This code uses colortbl to color the cells. It is know that there are viewer-dependent issues that make the lines (partly) disappear. One way to avoid this is to draw everything in `tikz`.

Comment: Thank you for the information! Do you know how can I set the thickness of the lines of our tables to match the ones in the cube

Comment: I am almost sure that the problem is just the viewer. What are you using? Okular has peculiar antialiasing, evince is better at high magnification, and `xpd` is normally bad. TikZ graphics are vectorial, so "resolution" has no meaning...

Comment: @Rmano Thank you very much for your response. I am using Document Viewer (Linux) and also I am viewing it in an Iphone with 458 ppi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This redraws your table with `tikz`. The line width is set to very thin, and the relevant positions in the code are marked. If this is the same line width as in the cube I do not know. Do you know the location of its code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}
\makeatletter
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\tikzset{matrix vlines/.style={execute at end matrix={
\foreach \XX in {1,...,\the\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns}
{\xdef\FitList{}
\foreach \YY in {1,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{\ifnodedefined{\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX}{\xdef\FitList{\FitList (\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX)}}{}
}
\node[fit=\FitList,draw=none,fill=none,inner sep=0pt,draw=none] (\tikzmatrixname-col-\XX) {};
}
\foreach \XX in {2,...,\the\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns}
{\draw[#1] ($(\tikzmatrixname-col-\XX.west)!0.5!(\tikzmatrixname-col-\the\numexpr\XX-1\relax.east)$)
coordinate (aux) (aux|-\tikzmatrixname.north)
 --  (aux|-\tikzmatrixname.south);
}
}},matrix hlines/.style={execute at end matrix={
\foreach \YY in {1,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{\xdef\FitList{}
\foreach \XX in {1,...,\the\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns}
{\ifnodedefined{\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX}{\xdef\FitList{\FitList (\tikzmatrixname-\YY-\XX)}}{}
}
\node[fit=\FitList,draw=none,fill=none,inner sep=0pt,draw=none] (\tikzmatrixname-row-\YY) {};
}
\foreach \XX in {2,...,\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}
{\draw[#1] ($(\tikzmatrixname-row-\XX)!0.5!(\tikzmatrixname-row-\the\numexpr\XX-1\relax)$)
coordinate (aux) (aux-|\tikzmatrixname.west)
 --  (aux-|\tikzmatrixname.east);
}
}},
matrix dividers/.style={matrix vlines=#1,matrix hlines=#1},
matrix frame/.style={execute at end matrix={
\draw[#1] (\tikz@fig@name.south west) rectangle (\tikz@fig@name.north east);
}}}
\makeatother
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{176, 170, 247}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\tikzset{local cs/.style={shift={(#1.south west)},x={(#1.south
    east)-(#1.south west)},y={(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)}},
    my mat/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,ampersand replacement=\&,
        matrix dividers=very thin,%<-
        matrix frame=very thin,%<-
        cells={nodes={minimum width=1.33em,minimum height=1.33em}}},
    cc/.style={fill=#1},cc/.default=myblue}
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix[my mat] 
        (tab) { 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \& |[cc]|  \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \& |[cc]| \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \& |[cc]| \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \& |[cc]| \\ 
        };
        \begin{scope}[local cs=tab,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=-1em]0,0)
         -- ([yshift=-1em]1,0) node[pos=5/12,below]{independent\\
         variables} node[pos=5/6,anchor=north west]{dependent\\
         variables};
         \draw[double=black,double distance=0.8pt,white,thick] (5/6,-0.2em) 
         -- ++(0,-1.6em);
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([xshift=1em]1,0) -- ([xshift=1em]1,1)
          node[pos=2/9,right]{test\\rows}
          node[pos=13/18,right]{training\\rows};
         \draw[double=black,double distance=0.8pt,white,thick]
         ([xshift=0.2em]1,4/9) -- ++ (1.6em,0);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    }
    \hfill
    \parbox{.45\linewidth}{
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[local cs/.style={shift={(#1.south west)},x={(#1.south
    east)-(#1.south west)},y={(#1.north west)-(#1.south west)}}]
        \matrix[my mat] 
        (tab) {
            \&  \&|[cc]|  \&  \&  \& |[cc]|  \\ 
            \&|[cc]|  \&  \&  \&  \&|[cc]|   \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
            \& |[cc]| \& |[cc=red]|  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
            \&  \&  \&  \& |[cc]| \&   \\ 
            \&  \&|[cc]|  \&  \&  \&   \\ 
        |[cc]| \&  \&  \&  \&  \& \\ 
            \& |[cc]| \&  \&  \&  \&  \\ 
            \&  \&  \& |[cc]| \&  \&|[cc]| \\ 
        };
        \begin{scope}[local cs=tab,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([yshift=-1em]0,0)
         -- ([yshift=-1em]1,0) node[pos=1/2,below]{no demarcation between
         independent\\ and dependent variables};
         \draw[thick,latex-latex] ([xshift=1em]1,0) -- ([xshift=1em]1,1)
          node[pos=1/2,right]{no\\ demarcation\\ between\\ training and\\ test rows};
        \end{scope}
       \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Delan At this point I have no access. Anyway you can change the line width at will till you are satisfied.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you did, but it looks way more better! I wish we had that chunk of code. Besides, there is a tricky part with the color. Check number the cell with number 5, it is like phosphorescent. I have been looking for it and it is almost impossible to get it.

Comment: @Delan My color picker says it has the RGB code `176, 170, 247`. That is, you can reproduce it with `\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{176, 170, 247}`.

Comment: You nailed it! It is 176, 170, 247. Thank you!!! I tried to compile it with standalone but it throws an error. Otherwise should I put what's before `\begin{document}` in my preamble?

Comment: @Delan You cannot use a `table` environment in standalone like this. Just drop `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}`.

Comment: .... my bad !!!

Comment: Can I add a second color? I need to color some cells with light blue and other, with grey

Comment: @Delan Yes. I added something that allows you to change the color. You could also define styles for each color. (I will decouple now.)

Comment: Marmot, check my updated OP. I took a screen shot with the cube along with our `\definecolor{myblue}{176,170,247}`. What do you think? I think the cube is still a little brighter

Comment: @Delan It is true that after the compilation the color picker will read off somewhat different values. By reverse engineering my color picker says one should use `\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{180, 171, 250}`. Please note that I have practically zero experience with this. You may ask a question specifically on that.